# Compiling the Mega.co.nz C++ sdk in OSX 10.8 with XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, macports

I installed macports and 5 required libraries and can't get this SDK to compile in a C++ command line application inside XCode.

The 5 libraries are

1. libcryptopp
2. openssl
3. readline
4. freeimage
5. curl

XCode is generating errors about undefined symbols for architecture x86_64. I started with about 100 but trimmed it down to 22 by correctly importing the libraries and setting the correct header search paths (/opt/local/include).  I really want to start playing with this SDK and I'm about at my wits end. There is no support on the site, no repo or version control, just a zip with some source files. Documentation doesn't spell out how the SDK works either.

If you can help I would be forever grateful. The SDK can be found by following this link 
https://mega.co.nz/#dev

Comment: Did you make any more progress? We know it can be done since the mega app is released...

Comment: I stopped trying. I'm waiting for a smart person to make a wrapper

Answer (score 0):

If it's still relevant you can check my Mega formulae pull request for Homebrew project.

Comment: Can you post a link or demonstration